# Why symfony2 it rendering the whole page?

Tags: html, symfony, safari, twig, reload

I’m working with Symfony2, and I have a **base.html.twig** view which includes a navbar and a logo. Also I have other views which extend the base.

When I go from one page that extends the base to another one, the whole page is being rendered in Safari even the navbar and the logo, the same when I reload the page.

Firefox works fine.

So, is there any option in symfony2 to force safari browser to reload just what the code says? (I don’t want to ask the user to install or configure anything in his/her computer).

I think I'm looking for something like that (but for Symfony2): [Livereload](https://github.com/mockko/livereload/blob/master/README-old.md)

Comment: What do you want? Do you want Safari reload a whole page when a user clicks some link on your page?

Comment: nothing like that, something work fine in Firefox and not in safari. clear cache in browsers and in symfony as well.

Comment: LiveReload helps you to view page after every `Cmd+S` in your IDE without `Cmd+R` in Safari. That's all about this. As I understood you before your last sentence you are talking about fetching data in ajax am I right?

Comment: I don't understand. You're rendering a view that extends your base layout (the whole page), so yes, the whole page is rendered. Can you please clarify your problem?

Comment: Sorry, I thought that when a page extends the base with the blocknotes tags, only the blocknotes tags where been rendering. In fact, in Firefox looks like if it were like this. For your answers, I see that I was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to make an AJAX requests to load only part of the whole page. You can use pure JavaScript or frameworks like jQuery, Dojo, Backbone.js, Ember.js, AngularJS, Spine.js, KnockoutJS, YUI, Batman.js, Closure, Agility.js, Knockback.js, React.JS. You can use any of them. They all contain AJAX-functionality.

But you need not only JS-framework to work with partial loading. You need also to organise your controllers on the server-side. Your controllers must not extend your `base.html.twig` but send in response only html-part or JSON-object that represent this html-part.